# Chrome doesn't have a icon?

Tags: google-chrome

I have downloaded and installed Chrome but couldn't find its icon in the dash. Is it normal?

I checked `/.local/share/applications` and there aren't any `.desktop` entries. I know locking Chrome to Launcher after starting it via terminal would do, but I wonder if it is normal for it to **not** have an icon after installation.

Comment: There are no `.desktop` files at all? What did you do to them?

Comment: @muru Nothing? But I don't have many applications installed yet.

Comment: Oh, `.local/share/applications`. Look in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: @muru Yeah it is there but why doesn't it show up in dash?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. You probably could not find Chrome icon not in Dash but in Launcher.

In Dash it could by found by typing first letters of it.

Then you could drag & drop the icon from Dash to Launcher or start Chrome and lock it in Launcher.

When you install software not using Software Center, it does not automatically add icons to Launcher.

P.S. You look for the `.desktop` file in a wrong place. It should be in `/usr/share/applications`.

**Update:** It looks like there is some bug in Ubuntu 15.10 that does not show the icon properly.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for answer but I literally stated that I can't find it in Dash, which is correct.

Comment: Also, I downloaded the `.deb` files but I installed that using Software Center.

Comment: I always find Chrome in Dash when install it this way. It may be some indexing issue that the icon did not appear right away.

Comment: Is the icon there now?

Comment: It is at `/usr/share/applications` and can be run from there yet even after locking it to launcher it doesn't show up in dash.

Comment: That is some sort of a bug. Try to reboot, or log off. How do you search in Dash? Do you type in `Chrome`?

Comment: Tried both. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: So do you type in Chrome? Or just click the Dash button? It does not show all applications by default.

Comment: I can run it from the icon at `/usr/share/applications` and lock it to launcher. Yet if I run it from terminal, it runs as a different application.

Comment: Open Dash and type there `Chrome`. What does it show? I am asking not about a terminal.

Comment: Not the Chrome browser but other random stuff from web etc.

Comment: You probably installed some webapps. Remove everything with chrome icon from `~.local/ahare/applications`.

Comment: It is a fresh install OS. And I have done that earlier. Maybe I should simply switch back to good old LTS version.

Comment: Installed 14.04 LTS and now it is working like it should.